# Laravel 5.2 login does not persist

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-routing

In my laravel application I executed php artisan make:auth and all the files were created to make Authentication work.

My AuthController.php code:

```
     /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';
    protected $loginPath = '/login';
    protected $username = 'username';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware($this->guestMiddleware(), ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'username' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|min:6|confirmed',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
            'hash-confirm' => md5($data['username']+Carbon::now()->resetToStringFormat()),
        ]);
    }
}
```

My User.php:

```
   /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password', 'hash-confirm',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
```

My routes.php:

```
Route::auth();
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('create', 'MessageController@create');
```

The thing is that if I put the username and password wrong it tells me it's wrong, when it's right it redirects me but when I get to the page after login the Auth::guest() is true and Auth::user() is null, so the session isn't created.
I use the latest version of laravel, so I don't need to put the middleware "web" group on the routes.

Thanks.

Comment: Once logged in, what does "return \Auth::user();" in your index method (home controller) return?

Comment: Indeed return the user logged in.

`$lang = substr(Request::server('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'), 0, 2);
        App::setLocale($lang);
        return view('index')->with('menu', false);`

This is what is in the index method. And after executing this it's logged in anymore.

Comment: What are you trying to do with the above code?

Comment: Change the locale and return the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same problem change the "id" field of the user table to:

```
$table->increments("id");
```

I had `$table->string("id")` to be able to generate the ID myself and it didn't persist the login.